# Identify use of C library functions that have locale-dependent behavior

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I would like to rid a C program of all uses of functions which have locale-dependent behavior, replacing them with similar functions which behave like their library counterparts in the "C" locale, regardless of the locale.

This is necessary for making the program into a library which will always have the same behavior for all inputs, even if linked into a program which invokes `setlocale`.

How can we get the GCC toolchain, in a glibc environment, to produce a diagnostic for every call to a locale-dependent C function?

This would be not only used to do the initial conversion, but also going forward to instantly catch situations when usage of such functions creeps into the program.

Comment: sounds like a task for a human

Comment: Hard question.  strcmp(): Is locale dependent when used as a callback in a qsort routine, for example. printf is ditto.  date/time functions.  I do not know of a list of std library functions that invoke locale.   But without locale how can you perform text I/O is you assume bytes instead of wchar_t ( for example) when you want your code to work everywhere.  Your assumption really limits the usefulness and portability of your code.

Comment: There is surely some way using `cflow --reverse` and `grep` that I am not clever enough for.

Comment: @jimmcnamara  I don't believe `strcmp` has this problem; the locale-dependent analog of `strcmp` is `strcoll`. Yes, I can perform text I/O without locale. The program has its own utf-8 conversion routines and even an I/O stream abstraction based on it. wchar_t is used throughout.

Comment: The locale dependencies are poorly documented in ISO C. For instance, the section about `setlocale` neglects to tell you that `strtoul` and `wcstoul` have this text in their descriptions: *"In other than the "C" locale, additional locale-specific subject sequence forms may be
 accepted."*

Comment: You can automatically get a list of _most_ locale-dependent functions with `nm /usr/lib/libc.so.6 | grep "_l$"`. To complete the list you have to do some manual search or repeat it with other libc implementations, e.g. *BSD ones (they got `*printf_l()`). Then use `#pragma GCC poison` to produce a diagnostic for each poisoned identifier usage.

Answer (score 2):

Per C 2018 5.2.1, the extended characters in the source and execution character sets are locale-specific. Therefore, every operation and function that works with characters may be affected by the locale. All functions in `<wchar.h>` and `<wctype.h>` are locale-dependent.

For operations and functions that only work on the numerical values and are agnostic about the interpretations of those values, you might consider them unaffected regardless of what characters are in the character set or what values they have. For example, the result of `'ü' - 'ö'` is locale-dependent, and so is `strcmp` on strings containing those characters, but this is a function of the values of `'ü'` and `'ö'`, not of the behavior of `-` or `strcmp`.

Per 5.2.2 1, the direction of writing is locale-specific, so all character output functions are theoretically affected.

Additional functions for which locale-dependent behavior is mentioned in the C 2018 standard are:

- `mbtowc`, `mbrtoc16`, `mbrtoc32` (6.4.4.4 11).
- All functions in `<ctype.h>` (7.4 2).
- All functions in `<locale.h>` (7.11).
- `strtod`, `strtof`, `strtold` (7.22.1.3 3).
- `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, `strtoull` (7.22.1.4 6).
- `mblen`, `mbtowc`, `wctomb` (7.22.7 1).
- `mbstowcs`, `wcstombs` (7.22.8 1).
- `strcoll` (7.24.4.3 2).
- `strerror` (7.24.6.2 4).
- `strftime` (7.27.3.5 3).
- `strtoimax`, `strotoumax` (7.8.2.3 defines them by reference to the other `strto` functions).
- `nan`, `nanf`, and `nanl` (7.12.11.2 defines them by reference to `strto` functions).
- `fscanf`, `scanf`, `sscanf`, `vfsscanf`, `vscanf`, `vsscanf`, `atof`, `atoi`, `atof`, `atoll` (defined by reference to functions above).

Implementation-dependent and other incompletely specified operations could be affected by locale. For example, `%p` for `fprintf` is specified to format a pointer in an implementation-defined manner, so an implementation might define it to depend on locale. Candidates for such behavior are listed in Annex J, “Portability issues.”

Comment: I am not sure this is complete, but I will leave it to others to track further references by indirection and to expand the lists of `<ctype.h>`, `<locale.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, and `<wctype.h>`.