# Is there a comprehensive list of functions affected by setlocale()?

Tags: c, posix, locale, crt

So we all know that calling `setlocale()` will cause lots of C runtime functions to change their behaviour depending on the currently active locale. For example, when using a German locale, `strtod()` will suddenly expect a comma to separate the integer from the fractional part of a number because that's the way floating point numbers are notated in German.

What I'm looking for is a complete list of **all** C runtime functions that are potentially affected by a call to `setlocale()`. The [man pages of setlocale](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) mention some functions but the list is far from complete, e.g. `strtod()` isn't mentioned there at all.

Why am I looking for such a list? I need to transition several projects from the portable "C" locale to the system's locale and I don't want to break anything so I need to grep for all C runtime functions that are potentially affected by a locale change in order to adapt or fix the code to be compatible with an arbitrary locale instead of just the portable "C" locale.

Comment: That same question never had any answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337287/identify-use-of-c-library-functions-that-have-locale-dependent-behavior

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale has a fairly long list, but I don't know if there is a complete list in the standards (C or POSIX)

Comment: the problem with this question is the word _complete_, making the answer unobtainium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this exists, but POSIX lists some functions that are directly dependant of locale and locale-relative variables [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition, **7 Locale**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html). I don't think this is exhaustive (I'm retty sure it is not). It is said:

> The standard utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of
>   POSIX.1-2017 shall base their behavior on the current locale, as
>   defined in the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section for each utility. The
>   behavior of some of the C-language functions defined in the System
>   Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 shall also be modified based on a
>   locale selection.

Which means (to me): read the manual of the functions...

You also have information about this in the standard C : **7.11.1 Locale control** :

> **7.11.1 Locale control**
>
> **7.11.1.1 The `setlocale` function**
>
> The setlocale function selects the appropriate portion of the
>   program’s locale as specified by the category and locale arguments.
>   The setlocale function may be used to change or query the program’s
>   entire current locale or portions thereof. The value `LC_ALL` for
>   category names the program’s entire locale; the other values for
>   category name only a portion of the program’s locale. `LC_COLLATE`
>   affects the behavior of the `strcoll` and `strxfrm` functions. `LC_CTYPE`
>   affects the behavior of the character handling functions, see 7.4) and the
>   multibyte and wide character functions. `LC_MONETARY` affects the
>   monetary formatting information returned by the `localeconv` function.
>   `LC_NUMERIC` affects the decimal-point character for the formatted
>   input/output functions and the string conversion functions, as well as
>   the nonmonetary formatting information returned by the localeconv
>   function. `LC_TIME` affects the behavior of the `strftime` and `wcsftime`
>   functions.

and

> **7.4 Character handling**
>
> **7.4.1 Character classification functions**
>
> **7.4.1.1 The `isalnum` function**
>
> **7.4.1.2 The `isalpha` function**
>
> **7.4.1.3 The `isblank` function**
>
> **7.4.1.4 The `iscntrl` function**
>
> **7.4.1.5 The `isdigit` function**
>
> **7.4.1.6 The `isgraph` function**
>
> **7.4.1.7 The `islower` function**
>
> **7.4.1.8 The `isprint` function**
>
> **7.4.1.9 The `ispunct` function**
>
> **7.4.1.10 The `isspace` function**
>
> **7.4.1.11 The `isupper` function**
>
> **7.4.1.12 The `isxdigit` function**
>
> **7.4.2 Character case mapping functions**
>
> **7.4.2.1 The `tolower` function**
>
> **7.4.2.2 The `toupper` function**

Comment: The forward references at the end of 7.11.1 could be regarded as a list, although it isn't specific but points at groups of functions.

Comment: @Lundin yes that's the problem, just forward references...